# How do I connect part 62113 together to form a ladder?

Tags: building

I am looking to build a ladder. I saw part 62113 and was wondering if its possible to connect part 62113? Here's what that part looks like:

[image: 32113]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to connect these together to form something like a ladder. One simple way is to use this fairly common arm element (30377):

[image: 30377]

This technique is shown on the ladder in the Creator Treehouse (31010):
[image: 31010]

Here are the relevant instruction steps in case it is hard to see in that photo:

[image: 31010 ladder step]